# How to manually mark files as moved/renamed using Tortoise Hg (mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have repository with a lot of files of different type (including binary files). The thing is I decided to restructure my repository and moved most of files (it is about 5G) to another folder (inside the same repository). So, of course, I want to use **find renames** tool in `Tortoise Hg` but since the are a lot of files application client freezes and after some time **stops responding**. I know that those files are only moved so **how can I manually force the TortoiseHg to mark them as renamed without using the tool**?

P.S. of course I can use this tool several time for only part of all files, but I want to know is it possible to do without find renames tool.

Answer (score 7):

You can try running the following command in the terminal:

```
hg addremove --similarity 90
```

This will effectively tell Mercurial to detect renames of files which are 90% similar.